# Problem storing SharePoint context in Provider hosted app hosted in a azure website

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, provider-hosted-app, azure

I created a provider hosted app, which I want to deploy in a azure website. The problem that I'm currently facing is that I don't have a SharePointContext after postback. I'm using the default way to create the sharepoint context like this.

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost();
```

The spContext variable is null after a postback

I looked into the two default TokenHelper and SharePointContext classes to see why this variable is null. The first time, a SharePointContext is created and saved in the session like this (SaveSharePointContext method).

```
httpContext.Session[SPContextKey] = spAcsContext;
```

After a postback, the class is trying to load the context from the session like this (LoadSharePointContext method)

```
return httpContext.Session[SPContextKey] as SharePointAcsContext;
```

This will return because inproc session is not available in my azure website. This makes sense because after a postback, my request might be handled by a different server.

I thought to work around this issue by not using inproc session management but using the azure redis cache for session management (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/)

The problem in this case is that objects stored in the session should be serializable. I can mark the SharePointContext object as serializable, but it contains a contextTokenObj variable which inherits from JsonWebSecurityToken. JsoWebSecurityToken is defined in a Microsoft dll which I can't mark serializable.

How can I store my SharePoint context so that I can reuse it after a postback? I don't want to recreate the context on every postback because it will have a negative effect on the performance.

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to mark the `SharePointContext`, `SharePointAcsContext` and `SharePointContextToken` serializable.

You must implement `ISeralizable` interface. In there are three method declaration. One constructor for the deserialization, and two for the serialization.

The following link refers to a msdn article, that's about how to implement it correctly. In that article, the second example explains the proper way on derrived classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182342.aspx

So, here is my code snippets:

SharePointContext:

```
protected SharePointContext(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        try
        {
            var tmp = info.GetString("spHostUrl");
            this.spHostUrl = new Uri(tmp);
        }
        catch (SerializationException) { }
        try
        {
            var tmp = info.GetString("spAppWebUrl");
            this.spAppWebUrl = new Uri(tmp);
        }
        catch (SerializationException) { }
        try
        {
            var tmp = info.GetString("spLanguage");
            this.spLanguage = tmp;
        }
        catch (SerializationException) { }
        try
        {
            var tmp = info.GetString("spClientTag");
            this.spClientTag = tmp;
        }
        catch (SerializationException) { }

        try
        {
            var tmp = info.GetString("spProductNumber");
            this.spProductNumber = tmp;
        }
        catch (SerializationException) { }
    }



    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    protected virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (spHostUrl != null) info.AddValue("spHostUrl", spHostUrl, spHostUrl.GetType());
        if (spAppWebUrl != null) info.AddValue("spAppWebUrl", spAppWebUrl, spAppWebUrl.GetType());
        if (spLanguage != null) info.AddValue("spLanguage", spLanguage, spLanguage.GetType());
        if (spClientTag != null) info.AddValue("spClientTag", spClientTag, spClientTag.GetType());
        if (spProductNumber != null) info.AddValue("spProductNumber", spProductNumber, spProductNumber.GetType());
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
```

SharePointAcsContext:

```
protected SharePointAcsContext(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        this.contextToken = info.GetString("contextToken");
        this.contextTokenObj = (SharePointContextToken)info.GetValue("contextTokenObj", typeof(SharePointContextToken));
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    protected override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);

        info.AddValue("contextToken", contextToken);
        info.AddValue("contextTokenObj", contextTokenObj);
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
```

SharePointContextToken:

```
protected SharePointContextToken(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info.GetString("Issuer")
            , info.GetString("Audience")
            , info.GetDateTime("ValidFrom")
            , info.GetDateTime("ValidTo")
            , JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<JsonWebTokenClaim>>(info.GetString("Claims")))
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    protected virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (Issuer != null) info.AddValue("Issuer", Issuer, Issuer.GetType());
        if (Audience != null) info.AddValue("Audience", Audience, Audience.GetType());
        info.AddValue("ValidFrom", ValidFrom, ValidFrom.GetType());
        info.AddValue("ValidTo", ValidTo, ValidTo.GetType());
        info.AddValue("Claims", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Claims));
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Here are the two zipped class: http://1drv.ms/1wy3E7B

ps: I am not fully satisfied with the `SharePointContext` constructor. If somebody know a better way, just share it.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected override bool ValidateSharePointContext(SharePointContext spContext, HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    SharePointHighTrustContext spHighTrustContext = spContext as SharePointHighTrustContext;

    if (spHighTrustContext != null)
    {
        Uri spHostUrl = SharePointContext.GetSPHostUrl(httpContext.Request);
        WindowsIdentity logonUserIdentity = httpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity;

        return spHostUrl == spHighTrustContext.SPHostUrl &&
            logonUserIdentity != null &&
            logonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated &&
            !logonUserIdentity.IsGuest &&
            logonUserIdentity.User == spHighTrustContext.LogonUserIdentity.User;
    }

    return false;
}
```

`spHighTrustContext.LogonUserIdentity.User` this get's null on second request in HighTrust On Prime